# How to get the user activity time?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, c#-4.0

i want to get the activity time of a user..

like when did he went away and when did he came back, for how much time he was away

Tables looks like this ..

```
id  deviceid    time      status

11  123-123     09:59     1
12  123-123     10:00     0
13  123-123     10:02     0
14  123-123     10:03     0
15  123-123     10:04     0 
16  123-123     10:05     1
```

at 10:00 he goes away .. and at 10:05 he comes back online .. i want to calculate the time when he was away..

Edit:

status = 0 means the user is away..
status = 1 means he is online..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "went away" and "came back"? Do you mean that he physically walks away from his computer/phone/tablet? That he looks away from his computer/phone/tablet to watch television for a bit? Or that he goes away from your website and comes back? Or switches away from his web browser window? Something else?

Comment: Writing records to a database table is the easy part.  Any tutorial can help you with that.  But what actual events are you looking to respond to here?  How do you define the terms "goes away" and "comes back"?

Comment: like walks away means .. everyone has a app installed in their phone.. which detects their location.. if some one is out of their position it updates the status as "Away" means 0 in this table .. and when they are back to their position it updates the status as "Online" means 1 in this table

Comment: It seems to me, based on your comment above, you need a few more columns in your database.  You have time (which is the current time), and I think you need a column that stores the time that status went to 0, a time stamp column that updates once status goes to zero, then another column  that tells you what the time differential is between the time and new time columns.

Comment: the time coloumn here tells us, when the status has changed .. it stores the time when status went to 0 or 1

Comment: Do you need to know each group of times the user was away or just the total amount of minutes? The difference is subtle but the changes to the query are significant.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you need the app that's installed on the phone to send the device ID of the phone it's running on, and the status of either Away or Online to some kind of API/service running on a server that will then write that data to the database along with the current timestamp. Which part of that process are you having trouble with?

Comment: And in your simple what should the result be? Is it 4 or 5?

Comment: Oh, I might have misunderstood. Are you just asking how to query the data that's stored, to see the total amount of time the user was away?

Comment: @SeanLange it should 4 .. becuase he was for 4 min, then he was back online..
Sorry if I didnt make my question clear

Comment: How about my other question? If they have two separate periods of being away do you want to total number of minutes away or do you need each group?

Comment: @SeanLange i need each group sir ..

Comment: @Elezar i need to see the amount of time he was away, in each group..

Comment: Then you need to do an islands type of query. There are dozens of examples around for this. The hard part is sometimes just knowing what to search for. Give it a look and see what you can find.

Comment: Since you say you want each group can you expand the sample data to have at least two time periods of being away? Also what do you want in the output for that type of situation? 3 columns? DeviceID, TimeAway, TimeReturned?

Comment: And where is the row for 10:01? Or do you not have that row? Or is the sample data a little flawed?

Comment: i googled island type of query as you said and it helped .. i am testing it lets see how it goes.. 
right now  i am calculating the gaps between the status changes

Comment: yea @SeanLange the data is flawed.. it was just a sample data that was typed  so it is my mistake .. i have records for every minutes once Employee comes online

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are well on your way to a solution. That is fantastic. We all learn the most by working through a challenging problem. Just for fun (I had a few minutes between projects) I tossed together a working example. I added some extra sample data and notated as such.

I learned this type of thing from Jeff Moden. He has an article about it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ID int
    , deviceid varchar(10)
    , StatusTime time
    , IsOnline bit
)

insert #Something
select 11, '123-123', '09:59', 1 union all
select 12, '123-123', '10:00', 0 union all --added by me
select 12, '123-123', '10:01', 0 union all
select 13, '123-123', '10:02', 0 union all
select 14, '123-123', '10:03', 0 union all
select 15, '123-123', '10:04', 0 union all
select 16, '123-123', '10:05', 1 
-- added some extra data here to simulate multiple groups
union all
select 17, '123-123', '10:06', 0 union all
select 18, '123-123', '10:07', 0 union all
select 19, '123-123', '10:08', 0 union all
select 20, '123-123', '10:09', 1 union all
select 21, '123-123', '10:10', 0 --This demonstrates that if the last value is away it will still count it as 1
;

with GroupedDates as
(
    select
        *
        , DATEADD(minute, - ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by deviceid order by StatusTime), StatusTime) as DateGroup
    from #Something
    where IsOnline = 0
)

select MIN(StatusTime) as StartTime
    , MAX(StatusTime) as EndTime
    , DATEDIFF(Minute, MIN(StatusTime), MAX(StatusTime)) + 1 as MinutesAway
from GroupedDates
group by DateGroup
```